# Force GridView to only a single row?

Tags: android

Is there a way to force GridView to only be a single row? Right now by default it will extend its height to accommodate all views supplied by its adapter

Comment: And how would you show, for instance, 100 items in only one row?

Comment: We could either truncate child views once the width of the control is reached, or scroll horizontally in a single strip.

Comment: Give fix height as per your row layout

Answer (score 0):

You Should combine a horizontal SCROLLVIEW and a LINEARLAYOUT and a GRIDVIEW to achieve what you want! 
put grid view in linearlayout and put the linear layout in the horizontal scroll view;

then when setting adapter! count the number of data!
after that you should calculate the desired width to show all your items!
for example you want to show 8 item! each width is 100dp . so the desired width would be 800dp!
then you should add these lines of code

```
yourGridView.setNumColumns(8);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
yourGridView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

dnt forget to set the width of the linear layout as WRAP_CONTENT in the xml!

*** IMPORTANT NOTE

as i know, by doing this, gridview can't garbage collection because Scroll View doesn't support such a thing and your grid view nested in it!
so dnt use this method for lots of images or you will get HEAP SIZE error!

Comment: could you plz provide an example ?